# Нужна критика парсера olx

Tags: python, парсер, requests, bs4, openpyxl

Код:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from threading import Thread
from openpyxl import Workbook
from time import sleep
from sys import stdout
from pympler import asizeof


def get_offers_data(html):
    """To get data from page`s offers"""
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    listHandler = soup.find('div', class_='rel listHandler')
    offers = listHandler.find_all('tr', class_='wrap')
    for offer in offers:
        thing = offer.find('td', class_='title-cell').find('a')
        title = thing.get_text(strip=True)
        offerLink = thing['href']
        tempVar = offer.find('img', class_='fleft')
        imgLink = tempVar['src'] if tempVar is not None else 'No img'
        tempVar = offer.find('p', class_='price')
        cost = tempVar.get_text(strip=True) if tempVar is not None else 'No cost'
        placeAndTime = offer.find('td', class_='bottom-cell').find_all('span')
        place = placeAndTime[0].get_text(strip=True)
        time = placeAndTime[1].get_text(strip=True)
        """print(
            f'Title: {title}\nLink: {offerLink}\nPict: {imgLink}\nPlace: {place}\nPime: {time}\nCost: {cost}\n----------------------')"""
        yield title, offerLink, imgLink, place, time, cost


def get_links(numberOfPages):
    """To get links to parse"""
    link = 'https://www.olx.ua'
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'}
    html = get(link, headers=headers).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    for linkBox in soup.find_all('div', class_='subcategories-list clr', limit=13):
        for link in linkBox.find_all('a'):
            link = link['href']
            for pageNumber in range(numberOfPages + 1):
                yield f'{link}?page={pageNumber}'


class Handler(Thread):
    """Class to request, handle and write to .xlsx book in thread"""

    def __init__(self, number, output):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'}
        self.number = number
        self.output = output
        self.working = True
        self.link = None

    def run(self):
        while self.working:
            # Check if has link to parse
            if None != self.link:
                html = get(self.link, headers=self.headers).text
                # print(f'[Thread{self.number}] {self.link}')
                # Parse page
                offersData = get_offers_data(html)
                # Add parsed data to excel book
                for offerData in offersData:
                    self.output.append(list(offerData))
                # Remove parsed link
                self.link = None
            sleep(.15)

    def handler_link(self, link):
        self.link = link

    def kill(self):
        self.working = False


def main():
    """To start other functions"""
    # Get some data from user
    multiply = int(input('Input the number of pages:'))
    numberOfThreads = int(input("Input 10:"))# :)
    bookName = input("Input the name of the book for output:") + '.xlsx'
    # Get links
    links = get_links(multiply - 1)
    maxCount = 151 * multiply
    count = 0
    # Initialize exel book
    book = Workbook()
    sheet = book.active
    # Set threads
    handlers = [Handler(x, sheet) for x in range(numberOfThreads)]
    for handler in handlers:
        handler.start()
    # Handle links
    for link in links:
        findHandler = False
        while not findHandler:
            # Find free thread
            for handler in handlers:
                if handler.link is None:
                    handler.handler_link(link)
                    stdout.write(
                        f'\rProcessing {count}/{maxCount}, the size of the book is {asizeof.asizeof(book) / 1000000}mb(Ram)')
                    findHandler = True
                    count += 1
                    break
                sleep(.15)
    # Stop all threads
    for handler in handlers:
        handler.kill()
    # Save data
    book.save(bookName)
    print(f'Succesfully saved to {bookName}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```